# ASP.NET core session keeps expiring regardless of the IdealTimout setting

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, coreclr

I have `asp.net core 1.1` application and i am setting the session timeout for 3 hours. So i am expecting the data in the session will remain for 3 hours.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // authorization                      
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        })
        services.AddKendo();
        services.AddSession();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {            
        //configure identity server 3
        app.UseIdentityServer(Configuration["Identity:Authority"],
            Configuration["Identity:ClientId"],
            Configuration["Identity:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
            domainService);

        app.UseSession(new SessionOptions()
        {
            IdleTimeout = new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0)
        });
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {                
        });

        // Configure Kendo UI
        app.UseKendo(env);

    }
```

However after remaining ideal for 20 mins, user's session gets timeout

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-1.1)

> The app uses the IdleTimeout property to determine how long a session
>   can be idle before its contents in the server's cache are abandoned.
>   This property is independent of the cookie expiration.

So there is timeout for data, and a separate timeout for session cookie. However based on [issue 169](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/issues/169) you cannot set timeout for session cookie.

My application is also using IdentityServer 3 and creates auth cookie which has longer timeout (more than 3 hours). and i dont think auth cookie has anything to do with session cookie.

**Questions**
Is there any other additional session related setting i need to do?
How can i check particular cookie's expiration time. On server i can not see that information in `Request.Cookies`. its just key-value pair.

Comment: In general, you're using in-memory sessions, since you have not configured a different session store. In-memory sessions are process-bound and volatile. They can be discarded simply due to memory constraints on the server, and will definitely be discarded if the process stops or the server is restarted. When hosting via IIS, the process is tied to the App Pool which defaults into "On Demand" mode, meaning it will actually shut itself down after a period of time, and then start back up when it needs to service a request again. If you want persistent sessions use Redis or SQL Server.

Comment: is it same as in-proc session in classic .NET?

Comment: Kind of. It's not exactly the same, but the same limitations apply.